# How to properly use the default instance of Apache2 in OS X Lion?

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx

I've got a clean installation of OS X Lion and I'd like to start using the default instance of Apache2 that comes installed. I've started Apache and placed a dummy index.html file in both `/Library/WebServer/Documents` and `/Users/username/Sites`, but when I navigate to `http://localhost/` or `http://localhost/~username/` I get a 404 Not Found error.

I've checked my `/etc/Apache2/httpd.conf` and `/etc/Apache2/users/username.conf` file and everything is pointing to the right directories, but no matter what I do I can not get it to serve the files located there. Can any one shed some light on the situation and tell me what I'm possibly doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It didn't work for me until I enabled Web Sharing in the "**Sharing**" Preferences.   Then I was able to view content stored in `/Users/username/Sites` using URL `http://localhost/username/`